# After running code, the output is always zero

Tags: c

I don't understand what makes the output zero.

I wanted to put 1000 as `x` and 100.00 as `y`, and I want the output to be `8000.00` not `00`.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int x,i;
    double y, result= x;
    scanf("%d %lf",&x,&y);

    for(i=0; i<3; i++)
    {
        y/=100;
        result = result+(result*y);
    }

    printf("%.2lf\n",result);
    return 0;   
}
```

Comment: `x` is uninitialised when `result` is assigned `x`. Then something is added to `result`, which therefore has no predictable value. Hence, undefined behaviour.

Comment: Your initialization of `result` to `x` gives it an undefined value, since at that point `x` itself is undefined.  Move the assignment to *after* the `scanf`.

Comment: so whats the solution...

Comment: After the correction mentioned by @TomKarzes the output isn't `8000.00` but `2020.20`. If you remove the decimal place limitation it is `2020.202000`.

Comment: code is executed top to bottom. `x` has a garbage value every line above the `scanf`

Answer (score -1):

You just declare the variable `x`, but not initialize it. So it causes undefined behavior.

`int x,i; // <-- you declare the variable, but you didn't assign a value to x`

Then, you assign `result` to `x`:

`double y, result= x; // so now result is undefined behavior`

Only now you give `x` a value by: `scanf("%d %lf",&x,&y);` but it's too late. `result` is now undefined behavior.

You should change your code to this:

```c
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int x,i;
    double y;
    scanf("%d %lf",&x,&y); // <-- now you give x a value
    result= x; // <-- so now result is not undefined behavior anymore.


    for(i=0; i<3; i++)
    {
        y/=100;
        result = result+(result*y);
    }

    printf("%.2lf\n",result);
    return 0;   
}
```